# EPPlus Excel AddPicture error 'Column number out of bounds'

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I have the following code:

The line with 'excelImage' initialization throws the exception: Column number out of bounds.
What is the solution of the problem?

```
var range2 = worksheet.Cells ["A" + limiter.ToString ()];
range2.Value = tokenGood.id; //Take from JSON-array
worksheet.Row (limiter).Height = 70; //'limiter' is like row iterator
worksheet.Column (1).Width = 10;

Bitmap img = new Bitmap(Image.FromFile (PIC_FILENAME));
OfficeOpenXml.Drawing.ExcelPicture excelImage = worksheet.Drawings.AddPicture ("random_string", img); //Error Line
excelImage.From.Column = 3;
excelImage.From.Row = limiter;
excelImage.SetSize (60, 60);
```

Answer (score 4):

Workaround for the bug (EPPlus 4.5.3 doesn't check if image resolution exists in: ExcelDrawing.cs,
internal void SetPixelWidth(int pixels, float dpi), line 400).

If image resolution doesn't set, just set it manually. AddPicture will work fine:

```
if (img.HorizontalResolution == 0 || img.VerticalResolution == 0)
   img.SetResolution(96, 96);                                       
var excelImage = worksheet.Drawings.AddPicture("img", img);
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in current (4.0.5) EPPlus. Even though the current version has been released recently, the backlog of open issues on [CodePlex](https://epplus.codeplex.com) is huge, so I don't see any approaching fixed release...

I solved it by downloading the source, manually correcting 4 rows in EPPlus/Drawing/ExcelDrawingBase.cs and recompiling.

The rows are 513, 515 (both in `SetPixelHeight(int, float)`) and 540, 542 (in `SetPixelWitdh(int, float)`).

I changed the occurrences of  `From.Column` or `From.Row` in those two lines to `Math.Max(From.Column, 0)` and `Math.Max(From.Row, 0)`.

The problem here is that the `From` property is an object that has somehow not been properly initialized, and the values of `From.Row` and `From.Column` are thus set to `int.MinValue` - which is not a valid column/row index, as you may guess.

I've been looking for workarounds that don't require to edit the source code, but couldn't find any: hope this helps.